# Sim Hot Swapping Android(Reading hot swapped sim)

Tags: android, performance

I am developing an android application, where `without being restarting the phone the sim is replaced(hot swap).`

The **main objectives** of this app are :

1. Read sim1 details and store (Done)
2. Hot Swap Sim1 by Sim2
3. Read details of Sim2 and store

The **problem** here is, `when i hot swap, I need to either restart my phone to get sim details or I have to put the phone to Flight/Airplane mode then back to Normal mode.`

Can anyone suggest me how to Read the Sim2 Details without restarting/putting in flight mode den back to normal mode?